# Redux values from a form generated dynamically

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am doing an application using react and redux, and I want to do some dynamics forms, to try that I had generate blocks of input, like a todo list app,here is an example:

```
<ul>
    <li>   
        <input type="text" ref="title" name="title" placeholder="title" autofocus/>
   </li>
   etc...
</ul>
```

But I don't know how I can get the values of these inputs, what is the best way to do this in Redux ? I made a lot of test using `ref`, but because my inputs are dynamically added I don't know how to implement this can you help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use refs unless you absolutely have to! The only use-case I can think of is for focusing them, or doing obscure DOM stuff.

For this, it's simply a matter of doing something like:

```js
class DynamicInputs extends React.Component {
  doSomethingWithValue(item, newValue) {
    // Here you can dispatch an action to update the value, etc.
  }
  
  renderItems() {
    this.props.items.map( item => {
      return (
        <input 
          value={item.value} 
          onClick={ev => this.doSomethingWithValue(item, ev.target.value)}
      );
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderItems()}</div>
  }
}
```

The idea is the `items` live in your redux store and are passed to this component as props. Then, you can dispatch actions to change those items in the `doSomethingWithValue` method. The method is handed the item so you can identify it, and the new value so you can update it.

If you want to be able to add todos, that is simply a matter of dispatching an action that pushes a new item to the `items` array :)

Comment: Ok, thanks :) I understand the idea I will try that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

export default class DynamicsInputs extends Component {

    doSomethingWithValue(item, newValue) {
        // Here you can dispatch an action to update the value, etc.
        console.log("item")
        console.log(item)
        console.log("newValue")
        console.log(newValue)
    }

    renderItems() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.items.map( item =>
                <input
                    value={item.value}
                    onClick={ev => this.doSomethingWithValue(item, ev.target.value)}/>

                )}
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                {this.renderItems()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

DynamicsInputs.propTypes = {

};
```

There was some small errors in the syntaxe but this version work for me thanks